# Need help generating a list in an async task

Tags: c#, async-await

I am trying to use an async task to read from my sqlite db using [sqlite.net](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net) and my basic class is this one below:

```
public class Students
{
    public string Fullname { get; }
    public string Admnumber { get; }

}
```

A quick example of implementing this library is:

```
public static IEnumerable<Students> QueryVals ()
{
    var db = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=assets\\mydb.db;New=False;Version=3");
    return db.Query<Students> ("select * from students");
}
```

but now when I try to use it an `async` task  as below:

```
public static Task<Students> GetStudentsList ()
{
    var db = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=assets\\mydb.db;New=False;Version=3");
    return db.Query<Students> ("select * from students");
}
```

I get an error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collection.Generic.List' to
>   'System.Threading.Tasks.Task'

even tyring this doesn't work:

```
private async void Init()
{
    IsBusy = true;
    var db = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=assets\\mydb.db;New=False;Version=3");
    var myitems = await db.Query<Students>("select * from students");

    IsBusy = false;
}
```

before I finish it gives the error that my class `Students` does not have GetAwaiter

Comment: For synchronous methods you have to create, start and return task.

Comment: @Sinatr Creating your own task wouldn't be appropriate here. Instead, you should use a different method that is asynchronous and returns a task.

Comment: Eek, I saw your edit. Definitely don't do `async void` unless you're doing an event handler. I think you need to read over [Async Await Best Practices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx).

Comment: You aren't using the async version, you could do this `return db.QueryAsync<Students> ("...");`

Comment: @AppSmata: You cannot await `db.Query`. You should call `db.QueryAsync`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't just make something asynchronous by changing the return type to `Task<T>`. Firstly, you need to switch to using the `SQLiteAsyncConnection` object and the async version of the `Query` method:

```
new SQLiteAsyncConnection("...");
...
db.QueryAsync<Students>("select * from students");
//      ^^^^^
//      Add this
```

Now you have two options. The first is to `await` the result, as shown in the [answer by mm8](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56170670/1663001). The other, and probably the one I would choose is to just return the task and let the caller `await`:

```
public static Task<IEnumerable<Students>> GetStudentsListAsync()
{
    var db = new SQLiteAsyncConnection("Data Source=assets\\mydb.db;New=False;Version=3");
    return db.QueryAsync<Students>("select * from students");
}
```

Note I'm also using the common convention of renaming the method to indicate it is async.

Comment: thanks for your hint. Awesome all your answers work and I dont know which to accept

Comment: Doesn't matter which, as long as you pick one, we both have enough reputation to not care about that :)

Comment: I would recommend [using `await` here rather than returning the task directly](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html), due to the possibility of exceptions from `SQLiteAsyncConnection`.

Answer (score 2):

A method that returns a `Task<T>` is supposed to either be `async` and `await` something or return a `Task`.

You could add the `async` keyword to your method and `await` the asynchronous `QueryAsync` method:

```
public static async Task<IEnumerable<Students>> GetStudentsListAsync()
{
    var db = new SQLiteAsyncConnection("Data Source=assets\\mydb.db;New=False;Version=3");
    return await db.QueryAsync<Students>("select * from students");
}
```

Or return an uncompleted task to be awaited by the caller of the method:

```
public static Task<IEnumerable<Students>> GetStudentsListAsync()
{
    var db = new SQLiteAsyncConnection("Data Source=assets\\mydb.db;New=False;Version=3");
    return db.QueryAsync<Students>("select * from students");
}
```

Comment: Not necessarily, this method doesn't need to be async and can just return the Task.

Comment: That's a different issue, one of convention.

Comment: should be  var db = new SQLiteAsyncConnection("Data Source=assets\\mydb.db;New=False;Version=3"); but then it returns the error Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collection.Generic.List' to 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task'

Comment: @AppSmata: Edited. Did you add the `async` keyword and change the return type?

Comment: yeah I did add a few details to the questions and I see you have edited your answer. I will test and see if it will solve my problem

Comment: I would recommend [using `await` here rather than returning the task directly](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html), due to the possibility of exceptions from `SQLiteAsyncConnection`.